# Не загружается точка (или просто отображение) текущей локации на карте в симуляторе (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Не загружается точка локации на карте в симуляторе, видна просто карта, хотя все вроде полностью прописано. 
Пока так:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код файла. Вроде бы все, что нужно было прописано:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    let regionRadius: Double = 1000


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       mapView.delegate = self
       locationManager.delegate = self
       configureLocationServices()
     }

    @IBAction func centerMapBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways ||   
              authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse{
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
        }
    }


}

extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func centerMapOnUserLocation() {
        guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate   
        else { return }
        let coordinateRegion =      
        MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius *  
 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
       }
   }

   extension MapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
      func configureLocationServices(){
          if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined{
             locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
          } else {
            return
       }
    }

     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,   
         didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
     centerMapOnUserLocation()
    }

}
```

Вот изображение (что бы увеличить, просто нажмите на него) plist-файла измененного в процессе работы. Добавлены последние три строки. Последняя отличается от той, что была в видео уроке. Среда настойчиво предлагала прописать так как в итоге и было прописано - "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description", в видео уроке же последняя строка имела несколько другой вид, а именно - "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription". Не знаю имеет ли это какое-то значение, привожу, так, на всякий случай:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы запустили проект, и у вас открылся Симулятор на верху тапните на `Debug`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем тапните на `Location` - `custom location`

должно выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо моих значений подставьте свои значения. Или оставьте широту и долготу по дефолту. Судя по всему у вас стоит `none`

Comment: Спасибо, я понял!

Comment: @Aresandro, Всегда пожалуйста, если ответ подошел, то отметьте галочкой пожалуйста.